# My flutter app showing black screen on Android because it can't connect to internet

Tags: android, flutter

Been working on this flutter project and everything's been going well. Now I'm done and want to deploy it to android but the app is not working on real android devices, I noticed the apps data usage is 0.00 so I tried adding all the permissions on android.xml, even added more security rules but all to no avail. Please has anyone ever encountered this and what was the solution?

Comment: What about the logs. Is there any error in logs? Try checking the logcat to get more details.

Comment: No errors... App works fine on Chrome Dev tools

Comment: Attach some logs when running on real android devices.

Comment: Were you testing using the app on web(Chrome Dev Tools)? Without any logs how will we know? Trying adding some print statements in main function to see if it is executing or not. ALso please tell is the app for web or for android?

Comment: Yes I'm using Chrome Dev Tools. But then you just saved my day, you made mentioned of checking my logcat for more details which skipped my mind before and I did and realized I didn't initialize FlutterBinding which I did and also added Google Services to my gradle dependencies as well as the firebase plugin... Thanks allot for your help guys. I guess all I needed was just some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happened was this

1st I didn't initialize FlutterBinding in my main.dart so I had to add it like this before Initialising my firebase

```
void main() async {
///Flutter binding initialized
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
///Firebase initialized
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

2nd (just to make sure everything works well) I added Google Services dependencies in my project level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'  // Google Services plugin
  }
```

And then firebase plugin in my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

and that's all... My app worked